# Instantiation of POCO objects with ServiceStack's IAppSettings is not working

Tags: servicestack

I have registered `AppSettings` within my `AppHost` as shown below:

```
container.Register<IAppSettings>(new AppSettings());
```

I have added following settings within my `web.config` file:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="baseaddress" value="http://example.com" />
   <add key="credential" value="{Username:foo,Password:bar}" />
</appSettings>
```

That's my service:

```
public class ExampleService : Service
{
    public IAppSettings Settings { get; set; }

    public void Post(ExampleRequest request)
    {
        // NOT WORKING -> always NULL!
        var credentials = Settings.Get<Credential>("credential", null);

        // OK
        var baseUrl = Settings.GetString("baseaddress");

        // more code...
    }
}
```

This is my `Credential` class:

```
public class Credential
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The `baseUrl` is always set but the `credentials` variable is always `NULL` and I don't know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest [v4.0.31 of ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md#v4031-release-notes) there's [First Class support for AppSettings](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md#first-class-appsettings) so you **don't have to** register it yourself as it's already registered for you:

```
container.Register<IAppSettings>(new AppSettings());
```

But I've tested this and it works as expected where it deserializes into a populated `Credential` instance with:

```
var credential = AppSettings.Get<Credential>("credential", null);
```

Are you sure you're using the exact key names? as your last sentence uses `baseUrl` and `credentials` but your appSettings says `baseaddress` and `credential`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like this in your config `<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">` to automatically add a security header to your post. Or you need to add and parse your own headers. You don't show your full web config or a sample call to your "Post" so I am running on some assumptions here.

Comment: I am not trying to do anything with the headers I just want to get a credential instance with the username and password set within the configuration file.

Comment: @westbeam87 Can you post your web.config? Or at least the relevant sections?