# ServiceStack IAppSettings was not ready and would result NULL reference exception if used in constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack, servicestack-ioc

It seems like the `IAppSettings` implementation was not ready from IoC in the constructor.

Before I go into details, I've read similar problems:

- [ServiceStack doesn't auto-wire and register AppSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38960882/2410655)
- [Instantiation of POCO objects with ServiceStack's IAppSettings is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25752004/2410655)

Both were answered by @mythz that he was not able to reproduce it.

#### From the Doc

"ServiceStack made `AppSettings` a first-class property, which defaults to looking at .NET's App/Web.config's.": https://docs.servicestack.net/appsettings#first-class-appsettings

And there is [default IoC registration already](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/ServiceStackHost.cs#L1223https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/ServiceStackHost.cs#L1223) in Funq to give you `AppSettings` when you ask for `IAppSettings`:

[image]

#### What I have

All my codes are in the repo: https://github.com/davidliang2008/MvcWithServiceStack

The demo app is just an ASP.NET MVC app (.NET 4.8) that built using the template, the simplest you can get, with ServiceStack (5.12.0) installed:

```cs
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        new AppHost().Init();
    }
}

public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("MvcWithServiceStack", typeof(ServiceBase).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            HandlerFactoryPath = "api";
        }

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
    }
}
```

Then I have a base class for the ServiceStack Service, and a `HelloService` just to demo:

```cs
public abstract class ServiceBase : Service { }

public class HelloService : ServiceBase
{
    public IAppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

    public object Get(HelloRequest request)
    {
        return new HelloResponse
        {
            Result = $"Hello, { request.Name }! Your custom value is { AppSettings.Get<string>("custom") }."
        };
    }
}

[Route("/hello/{name}")]
public class HelloRequest : IReturn<HelloResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

#### What works

When you're not using `IAppSettings` in the constructor, whether in the `HelloService` or its base class `ServiceBase`, everything works out fine.

When you clone the project to your local, if you navigate to `/api/hello/{your-name}`, you will see its response would be able to get the custom value from web.config:

[image: // TODO: attach screenshot]

#### What doesn't work

When you're trying to get the `IAppSettings` and initialize something else with some app setting values in the constructor - whether it's in the child class or the base class, `IAppSettings` will fail to get the implementation from IoC, and result a NULL reference exception:

```cs
public abstract class ServiceBase : Service
{
    public IAppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

    public ServiceBase()
    {
        // AppSettings would be NULL
        var test = AppSettings.Get<string>("custom");
    }
}
```

OR

```cs
public class HelloService : ServiceBase
{
    public HelloService()
    {
        // AppSettings would be NULL
        var test = AppSettings.Get<string>("custom");
    }
}
```

[image: // TODO: attach screenshots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use any property dependency in the constructor since the properties can only be injected after the class is created and the constructor is run.

You'll only be able to access it in the Constructor by using constructor injection, e.g:

```cs
public class HelloService : ServiceBase
{
    public HelloService(IAppSettings appSettings)
    {
        var test = appSettings.Get<string>("custom");
    }
}
```

Or accessing the dependency via the singleton:

```cs
public class HelloService : ServiceBase
{
    public HelloService()
    {
        var test = HostContext.AppSettings.Get<string>("custom");
    }
}
```

Comment: So to make sure I understand it correctly, `Container.Register(AppSettings)` would default as a property injection if I don't inject it from the constructor, and that's why it worked? And it would also work for constructor injection?

And again, thanks a lot for the quick response! It's the fastest and greatest customer service ever!

Comment: Yeah, if you don't use constructor injection, it can only be populated by property injection. The IoC isn't doing anything special to create the class, it just creates an instance of it then assigns each of its public properties by resolving the type in the IoC. It can only assign properties of a class after an instance of it is created which is why all injectable properties will be null when trying to access it from the constructor.

Comment: Yea I should've noticed that's a property injection, because when I did `public IAppSettings AppSettings { get; private set; }`, it didn't work. It has to have a `public` or `protected` setter at least.

Comment: @DavidLiang Injectable properties should always be public.

Comment: Yeah, but that's kind of against my "not-so-seniored-programming-best-practices" to always have a public setter.

Comment: @DavidLiang An external class, I.e. an IOC needs to assign it so it should be public, it also needs to be public to be able to test it. The class should be correctly defined, not following some predetermined preferences. If you don’t want injectable properties public then you’ll need to use constructor injection everywhere.